# Batch file out put to both console and text

Tags: batch-file, logging, console, output

How can I save the out put of a batch file to a text file and the output should be displayed on console too.

For Eg:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Hello World 
@pause
```

It will show Hello World on console

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Hello World >text.txt
@pause
```

It will save Hello World to text.txt

How can I make it both happen together?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I echo and send console output to a file in a bat script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503846/how-do-i-echo-and-send-console-output-to-a-file-in-a-bat-script) and [Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file).

Comment: Am new to console application. If my understanding is wrong please pardon. I checked the above link. By using the link i could direct all the logs to the same file. But while doing it no message is appearing on console. What i need is the console should show the messages and at the same time the messages that appearing on console should be logged in to a file.

Comment: @user3647205 You should very carefully read EVERYTHING of existing questions. [jeb](http://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) explained in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4588136/3074564) that it is not possible to output a text to console window and at the same time redirect to a file using only Windows command processor. But jeb posted also a comment below his answer to JScript/Batch hybrid __tee__ written for this task. [rojo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo) posted here the link to this solution once again. The other answers contain also various __tee__ solutions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file does not satisfy my requirement. It is directing the console stdout and/or stderr to log file. But either of logging or watching in console only happens.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239924/windows-batch-tee-command guided to satisfy the both cases. But it is not consistant when i tried. Sometimes it will log and show the messages. but sometimes it is not for the same command. I dont know whats going

Comment: .My exact aim is to run a batch file from vba excel and wait till it finishes the execution and check the error log to see the execution was success or not before proceeding. And i want to see the console messages also. Any suggestion will be helpful. I am using Wscript to run the bat file from vba.

Comment: The duplicate `tee` command was already deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'FOR' command if you want: (yea this one only execute 1 command)

```
For /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('ECHO Hello world') do (
  echo %%a
  echo %%a >text.txt
)
```

But the solution below only useful if you want to send both output to console and file a command that show a lots of texts like 'SET' command.
So what about you create an external batch file then use it in your main file?
Example: Code for 'printBoth.bat'

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set string=
:loop
set string=!string!%1
shift
if not "%1"=="" goto loop

For /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('!string!') do (
  echo %%a
  echo %%a >text.txt
)
```

Now if you want to print to both console and file, just type this code: `call printBoth.bat [type command in here]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the outputs of commands:

```
if exist "file.txt" del file.txt /f /q
for /f "delims=" %%k in ('command here') do (
  echo %%k
  echo %%k>>file.txt
)
```

1. Note the `>>`. Don't use `>`. `>` would remove all the text in the file, then write the first output-ed line in the command, which is not good if there were multiple lines that will be "echo-ed" by `FOR`. `>>` creates a new line instead of replacing the line like `>`.
2. `DELIMS=` works like `TOKENS=*`, but `DELIMS=` won't include the executed command.

I added `if exist "file.txt" del file.txt /f /q`, in order to not append the new output-ed lines. You can remove that if you want to append the lines to the file.

For customized `ECHO` outputs,

```
@echo off
echo TEXTHERE & echo TEXTHERE >>file.txt
echo TEXTHERE2 & echo TEXTHERE >>file.txt
rem ...and so on
```

1. `<command1> & <command2>` means "do `<command1>`, **then do** `<command2>`"
2. If you don't want to append, use `>` instead of `>>`.

Comment: `"tokens=*"` removes leading spaces. Therefore I would use `"delims="` instead. (watch the difference with a command like `dir`) See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551379/how-do-i-make-a-log-of-all-echo-commands-in-a-batch-file/15553922#15553922) for some other ideas to do it.

Comment: Now I'd use `delims=` instead, because the `dir` command will be included if I use `tokens=*`.