# How to redirect output to two different (device) files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

Is it possible of a single command to two different files/devices?

```
echo Hello World>lpt1>con
```

Comment: You are essentially asking for the Unix equivalent of the `TEE` command.  There isn't a native tool on Windows to do that with a batch script.  But if you search StackOverFlow with: `[batch-file]tee`, you might find some work arounds.

Comment: Well it could be easy to split it into two lines or even use `&` if needed but I just wanted to know if DOS(--Windows) had any support for these things

Comment: DOS didn't have it and neither does Windows cmd.exe.

Comment: But then we would have to re-execute the command twice then

Comment: So the only logical solution would be to store the output in a buffer(file) and then re-direct the both the devices one by one

Comment: This superuser thread should help.  Seems the answer is use Powershell. https://superuser.com/questions/74127/tee-for-windows

Comment: There is a cheap batch-only solution, [I posted seven years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15553922/2152082). Not ideal because it uses a temporary file, but working.

Comment: In PowerShell, there is `Tee-Object`.

Comment: There is no way that a _single command_ output to _two devices/files_ via a switch or any combination of OS features in Windows or any other OS, unless the command/program be specifically written to do that (in which a case, there is no way that such a program output to a single device/file). In Unix the TEE (like a pipeline "T") command do that. There is not any standard TEE command on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the output to a variable using a one-liner:

`FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('echo Hello World') do (SET VAR=%%g)`

Then, you could send that to a file:

`echo %VAR%>>file.txt`

`echo %VAR%>>file2.txt`