# Create a log file with execution summary of a cmd script

Tags: cmd

I have a long and complicated cmd script which asks the user few questions and then after creates complicated directory structure of nested folders.

I would like to modify it, so that it will create a .txt file with everything that is shown in the command window during execution, with all eventual errors included.

I tried several methods but unsuccessfully. I believe the most simple way is to put the entire content in brackets, like this:

```
(
the content with all commands is here
)> log.txt 2>&1
```

However this brakes it and question points where user input is required are not displayed correctly. I tried to reduce the brackets for only the part of the code where the actual work (folders creation) is done. Yet, after the first bracket it interrupts and just closes instantly.
This is strange, since the same thing is working when I am trying it with more simple scripts. Any ideas of how this can be done will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track: redirect the whole thing to the file. You can override this redirection for selected commands by explicitly redirecting its output somewhere else (screen is `con:` (as in console)):

```
@echo off
setlocal 
call :payload >output.txt
goto :eof

:payload
echo hello (to the file)
>con: echo this goes to screen.
echo hi to the file
>con: set /p "input=Input: "
echo input to the file: %input%
```

Comment: but as it reaches the first bracket, it suddenly stops - and I don`t know why

Comment: because an unescaped `)` closes the code block unintentionally. See my changed answer, which solves the issue better than escaping it (as `echo hello(world^)`.

Comment: and how can I split it to be displayed both on the screen and recorded in the file at the same time?

Comment: `cmd` has no such functionality, but you can emulate it. See my two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551379/how-do-i-make-a-log-of-all-echo-commands-in-a-batch-file). If you are willing to use a third-party solution, google for `tee for windows`.